# New to JAVASCRIPT issue with IF Statement and multiple values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a page which is a form that can either have 33 questions or 28 questions depending on which form the user selects. The form calculates the score of the user depending on what they select. The forms works fine when it is just one form but I need it two work differently since some questions causes the score to go down instead of up if the user selects it. here is the JAVASCRIPT I am using. The code before only had one if statement qtn_nbr <=16. I added the new var form_nm which tells me if the form needs to subtract at 16 or 18 questions. However the below code is recognizing only the first if statement for 18 but when I switch to the form for 16 it does not go to the else if even though the value is 16 now for the form_nm. Can someone please look at my syntax and let me know if I am missing something or if they have a better logic for me to switch between these two values? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function valuechanged(inval, totalqtns)
{
    //alert(inval.name);
    //alert(inval.value);
    var val = inval.value;
    var str = inval.name;
    var qtn_nbr = String(str).substring(4);//get the number of the question
    
    var formnm = document.getElementById(formname); //get question number

    //alert(qtn_nbr);
    var txt1 = 'pos_pt_' + qtn_nbr;
    //alert(document.getElementById(txt1).value);
    var txt2 = 'pt_' + qtn_nbr;
    var txt3 = 'qtn_' + qtn_nbr + '_comm';
    var txt4 ='comm_' + qtn_nbr;
    //alert('here');//current display of here when clicking on any point value!
    document.getElementById(txt2).value= 0;
    //alert(document.getElementById(txt2).value);
    if (formnm = 18 && qtn_nbr <= 18)
    {
        
            if (val == 'yes')
                {
                document.getElementById(txt2).value = document.getElementById(txt1).value;
                //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = true;
                document.getElementById(txt3).value='';
                document.getElementById(txt4).value='';
                }
            else if (val == 'half')
                {
                document.getElementById(txt2).value = parseInt(document.getElementById(txt1).value)/2;
                //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
                }
            else
                {
                document.getElementById(txt2).value = 0;
                //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
                }
        
    }
    else if (formnm = 16 && qtn_nbr <= 16)
    {
        
        if (val == 'yes')
            {
            document.getElementById(txt2).value = document.getElementById(txt1).value;
            //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById(txt3).value='';
            document.getElementById(txt4).value='';
            }
        else if (val == 'half')
            {
            document.getElementById(txt2).value = parseInt(document.getElementById(txt1).value)/2;
            //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
            }
        else
            {
            document.getElementById(txt2).value = 0;
            //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
            }
    
    }   
    else
        {
        document.getElementById(txt2).value = - parseInt(document.getElementById(txt1).value);  //negative points
        }
    
    
    //alert(document.getElementById(txt2).value);
    var totval = calctotal(totalqtns);
    document.getElementById('total').value = totval;

}
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning values, `==` and `===` are for comparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks for the help. Instead of setting the variable if I used the value within the if statement then it worked with the ==.

```
    if (document.getElementById('formname').value == 18 && qtn_nbr <= 18)
    {
        
            if (val == 'yes')
                {
                document.getElementById(txt2).value = document.getElementById(txt1).value;
                //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = true;
                document.getElementById(txt3).value='';
                document.getElementById(txt4).value='';
                }
            else if (val == 'half')
                {
                document.getElementById(txt2).value = parseInt(document.getElementById(txt1).value)/2;
                //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
                }
            else
                {
                document.getElementById(txt2).value = 0;
                //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
                }
        
    }
else if (document.getElementById('formname').value == 16 && qtn_nbr <= 16)
    {
        
        if (val == 'yes')
            {
            document.getElementById(txt2).value = document.getElementById(txt1).value;
            //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = true;
            document.getElementById(txt3).value='';
            document.getElementById(txt4).value='';
            }
        else if (val == 'half')
            {
            document.getElementById(txt2).value = parseInt(document.getElementById(txt1).value)/2;
            //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
            }
        else
            {
            document.getElementById(txt2).value = 0;
            //document.getElementById(txt3).disabled = false;
            }
    
    }
```